# Is there a way to generate a multi-configuration launch.json file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, launch

Whenever I open a folder (.NET solution) with several projects in VSCode, I get prompted to *.NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug* - however, this lets me pick only 1 of the projects to generate the configuration for.

I tried executing the command again, but I get prompted to *Replace existing build and debug assets* - I was hoping for appending new configurations this way instead.

I'm currently manually adding configurations to the **launch.json** file for each of the projects that I want to run in parallel, and referencing them inside the **compounds** section - this works, but I was hoping for a faster and less error-prone way.

Does anyone know of a "shortcut" of some kind that would generate multiple configurations in an automated way, possibly neatly packing them into a compound as well?